# Using jQuery or javascript to remove cycling inline height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to figure out how to fix the issue with my slider. When it slides the next slide temporarily appears below the first slide and pushes the other elements down.

Here is the site. http://upperdeck.dev.warp9inc.com/

There is a script somewhere that is adding an inline height to the `<li>` tags. I cannot figure out which one it is. I know I can set a height for the main container and set overflow as hidden, however, if I do this than the images will not resize correctly when stretching and shrinking the screen size and allow the content below the slider to move with it.

I am guessing that if I removed how it adds the height to the list tag every time it cycles then maybe that would fix it.

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I think you just need to fix your CSS.  Make your container `position:relative` and your slides `position:absolute`.  Looks like they're trying to take the same space, but the CSS isn't set up for it

Comment: I just tried that via the inspection tool and that didn't seem to work. I tried the container and the `ul` tag to `relative` and the `li` tags to `absolute` but the content below it hides under the images. Any more thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a crazy work around. I removed the 'relative positioning' and added a placeholder image under the slider to keep my other elements from disappearing under it. Not a great solution but a fix!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `position: relative !important;` on the `li`'s means they will be located relative to where they would normally be placed in the layout. So when you then say `top: 0px;`, that actually means "0 pixels from where I should be placed in the layout", and when two of your slides are set to `display: block;` at the same time, one is laid out beneath the other. This is causing it to push the other slide down.

The easiest fix I can see is to remove `position: relative !important;` from the slides, and set the height of the list to the height of your slides.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! The only problem with removing the relative is the content below it then hides under the slides. The slider is suppose to resize as you change the width of your screen with that content below it following up and down with it. So if I set a height to the images then the content below it will be far down the page when shrinking the screen. Make since?

Comment: This also fixes the height issue. I'm not sure exactly why, but I assume the height calculation performed by the script is getting an incorrect value when the absolute positioning of the slides is overridden.

Comment: I removed the 'relative' and now it doesn't seem to be wanting to resize as your shrink the screen and etc. Any ideas?

Comment: I see. It gets a bit more complicated in that case.